# Need help redirecting variables in a batch file to comma delimited textfile

Tags: batch-file, redirect

Can some one please help me with this.

i have 5 variables in a batch file which were entered in thru prompts

```
set Name=john smith
set address=25 center street
set city=Hackenack
set state=NJ
set zip-07601
```

I want to create a comma delimited output text file called clients.txt that will contain the content of the variables all on one line separating the fields with commas.

I'm going to have hundreds of input records with different values in the variables.

I just need help showing me how to redirect the variables to  one output record.
 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET /P name="Name? "
SET /P address="Street address? "
SET /P city="City? "
SET /P state="State? "
SET /P zip="Zip? "

echo %name%,%address%,%city%,%state%,%zip% >> clients.txt
```

If you want it to be a true CSV format, you'll need to enclose the values entered with quotation marks, like this.

`echo "%name%","%address%","%city%","%state%","%zip%" >> clients.txt`

If you want the text file to be entirely one line (not one line per grouping) then

`set /p I="%name%","%address%","%city%","%state%","%zip%" <NUL >> clients.txt`

and for each subsequent `set /p I=stuff<NUL >>clients.txt` the data will be written appended to the first line, no line breaks.

**Explanation**

When you echo data with a single `>` text that would have been output to the console is instead redirected to a new output file, overwriting the destination file if it already exists.

When you echo data with a double `>>` the output is appended to an existing file without overwriting (or creates if the file doesn't exist yet).

Appending without a line break is a little trickier, and requires a little hackery: `set /p var=text to append<NUL >>outfile.txt`.  If you need more details, leave a comment and I'll try to explain *why* that works the way it does.